# WordPress Show Single Post on Home Page with previous/ Next Button

Tags: theme-development

I am new to WordPress and recently doing some stuff with WordPress.

I am using WordPress and want to make theme.

I want to show a full post on the home page and at the bottom I want to show next and previous post links.

There will only be one category in which I will post and only one post will display on the home page at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the number of blog posts to show at Settings->Reading from 10 to 1 might do it for you.

Comment: Adding to this. I think you need to make sure that the WP-PageNavi plugin is installed. Most themes support this including default Wordpress themes (twentyten & twentyeleven) so you can refer to those as an example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a php template to display a [Page of Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#A_Page_of_Posts). See codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy to ensure that the page you create will use this template.
2. Use the [next_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link) function and the related previous_post_link() function to display the links.
3. Create a page in WordPress to act as your front page (doesn't need to have any content in it).
4. In the WP Admin, under "Settings" > "Reading", set the front page to the page you created in #3.